# Decoding json object retrieved from PHP in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am having trouble using the json object echoed from php to javascript. In the php file I define

```
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';
echo($json);
```

and then in javascript file I want to access this object.

```
$("#test_btn").click(function() {
                $.get("serverside.php", function(data, status) { 
                   console.log("data " , data["a"]); //undefined
                   console.log(JSON.parse(data)); // error
                });
            });
```

I get undefined for data["a"] and an error for JSON.parse. How should I use the returend data?

Comment: Use an associative array and echo it with `json_encode`. Don't create your own JSON, it's prone to errors.

Comment: Accually I am reading a Json file in php. I had trouble with that so I made this test. I get file content using file_get_contents($url) but I had the same problem when reading data in javascript

Comment: Try just `console.log(data)` and see what it outputs. You're probably not getting valid JSON

Comment: Which error are you getting? The error message usually helps.

Comment: I think I realized the problem, yet I don't know how to solve it! in the php file, I am reading the content of several json files, so I loop through all the files and echo in the loop. I thought the content of each file comes separately but accually what I get is a "{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}..." which is not valid json

Comment: The error was "JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 32" which is due to invalid data returned.

Comment: Read the contents of all your json files and put them in a PHP array with json_decode function. Once they're in a format you're happy with export them with json_encode.

Comment: Don't add them as a string. They need to be handled as a PHP array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comment (echoing several json strings), you should do the following:

1. Initialize an empty results array;
2. Read your file and put it in an array or object using `json_decode()`;
3. Add this array / object to your results array;
4. At the end, use `json_encode()` to encode and echo out your results array.

Answer (score 1):

You must make a `JSON.parse(data)` before attempting to access to `data['a']`, and send a header from PHP that implicitly say the browser that the data output is going to be a JSON.

```
header ('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Comment: jQuery will make an intelligent guess and if it recognizes the json, it will be parsed already by the time you get it.

Comment: It doesn't matter to the order of `JSON.parse(data)` on success callback, as it actually trigger an error which indicates it just parsed invalid json.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that PHP is returning a string that looks like JSON.

In JS it might help to JSON.parse(data) to convert from string to JSON object, then you can access it.

```
$("#test_btn").click(function() {
  $.get("serverside.php", function(data, status) {
    $json = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log("data " , $json["a"]); // should now return 1
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to put json_encode or parse it in javascript